# C++ Работа со структурой с помощью указателей (ошибка во время выполнения)

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры

Здравствуйте. Работаю со структурой с помощью указателя, массива указателей. Во время выполнения программа выдаёт ошибку. Подозреваю, что что-то не так с указателями. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<cstdio>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

const int N=10;

struct PlaneDescr  //объявление структуры
{
char *PlaneName;
float FlightDistance;
int PlaceNumb;
int EngineNumb;
double DepartureTime;
int FlightHours;
int FlightMinutes;
double ArrivalTime;
 };

 PlaneDescr Planes[N];      //Глобальный массив из N структур типа PlaneDescr
 int poisk(int j);  //Функция поиска данных в глобальный массиве 
 void print_st(int num); //Функция вывода элементов структуры из глобальнго массива
 PlaneDescr *init_ptr(void); //функция для инициализации структуры типа PlaneDescr
 void print_ptr(PlaneDescr *);  //Функция вывода элементов структуры

int main()
{
    int i=0,j,a;
    PlaneDescr arrplane[N];   //массив з N структур
    PlaneDescr *arrpln[N];    //массив указателей на структурный тип PlaneDescr
    PlaneDescr *sptr;       //указатель на структурний тип PlaneDescr
    sptr=arrplane;      //Аналогично sptr=&arrplan[0];

    while (a&&i<N)    //Ввод элементов массива структур arrplane[N]
{
    cout<<"Введите название самолёта: ";
    cin.getline(sptr->PlaneName, sizeof(sptr->PlaneName));
    cout<<"Введите дальность полёта (через '.', в километрах): ";
    cin>>sptr->FlightDistance;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество мест: ";
    cin>>sptr->PlaceNumb;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество двигателей: ";
    cin>>sptr->EngineNumb;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите время вылета (через '.'): ";
    cin>>sptr->DepartureTime;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество часов, проведённых в воздухе: ";
    cin>>sptr->FlightHours;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество минут, проведённых в воздухе: ";
    cin>>sptr->FlightMinutes;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите время прибытия (через '.'): ";
    cin>>sptr->ArrivalTime;
    cin.ignore();

    cout<<"\nХотите ввести дополнительную информацию о самолёте? y/n"<<endl;
    char ans=getche();
    cout<<endl;
    if (ans=='n' || ans=='N') a=0;
     sptr++;//переходим к следуюзей структуре в массиве arrplane[N]
     i++;
   }

    cout<<"Вывод значений элементов массива структур arrplane[i] с использованием указателя\n ";
    j=i; sptr=&arrplane[0];
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
        print_ptr(sptr);
        arrpln[i]=new PlaneDescr; //выделение динамической памяти для структуры в куче
        arrpln[i]=sptr;     //инициализация элементов локального массива
        sptr++;
    }
  cout<<"Ввод недостающих значений элементов массива структур с использованием массива указателей "<<endl;
  for (i=j; i<N; i++)
      arrpln[i]=init_ptr(); //Выделение памяти для структуры в функции
  cout<<"Вывод значений элементов массива структур с использованием массива указателей\n "<<endl;
  for (i=0; i<N; i++)
   { print_ptr(arrpln[i]);
     Planes[i] = *arrpln[i]; //Инициализация элементов глобального массива cтруктур
   }
  cout<<"Вывод 3 первых значений элементов глобального массива структур\n";
  print_st(N-7);

  cout<<"Введите время вылета для поиска первого в массиве структур самолёта: "<<endl;
  cin>>j;
  a=poisk(j);
  if (a!=-1) print_ptr(&Planes[a]);
     else    printf("Нет таких самолётов");
  for ( i=0; i<N; i++)  delete arrpln[i]; //Освобождение памяти в "куче"
  getch();
  return 0;
}//End main()----------------------------------------------------------
 int poisk(int j)   //Функция поиска данных (data[i].day==j)
  {int a=-1;        //в глобальном массиве структур data[i]
   for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    if (Planes[i].DepartureTime==j) { a=i;
                                        return a;}
   return a;
  }//------------------------------------------------------------
 //print_st() -Функция вывода элементов структуры из глобальнго
 void print_st(int num)            //массива, num -количество
{
    for (int i=0; i<num; i++)      //структур для вывода
    {
        cout<<"\tСамолёт"<<Planes[i].PlaneName<<" летит на расстояние "<<Planes[i].FlightDistance<<" км,"<<" перевозит "<<Planes[i].PlaceNumb<<" пассажиров,"<<endl;
        cout<<"имеет "<<Planes[i].EngineNumb<<" двигателей,"<<" вылетает в "<<Planes[i].DepartureTime<<", прибывает в "<<Planes[i].ArrivalTime<<endl;
        cout<<"и находится в воздухе "<<Planes[i].FlightHours<<" часов "<<Planes[i].FlightMinutes<<" минут."<<endl;
    }
}//------------------------------------------------------------
 //init_loc() -функция для инициализации структуры типа PlaneDescr
 PlaneDescr *init_ptr(void)
{
    PlaneDescr *spt = new PlaneDescr;      //Выделение памяти в "куче"
    cout<<"Введите название самолёта: ";
    cin.getline(spt->PlaneName, sizeof(spt->PlaneName));
    cout<<"Введите дальность полёта (через '.', в километрах): ";
    cin>>spt->FlightDistance;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество мест: ";
    cin>>spt->PlaceNumb;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество двигателей: ";
    cin>>spt->EngineNumb;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите время вылета (через '.'): ";
    cin>>spt->DepartureTime;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество часов, проведённых в воздухе: ";
    cin>>spt->FlightHours;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите количество минут, проведённых в воздухе: ";
    cin>>spt->FlightMinutes;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"Введите время прибытия (через '.'): ";
    cin>>spt->ArrivalTime;
    cin.ignore();
    return spt;
}//------------------------------------------------------------
 void print_ptr(PlaneDescr *pdt)  //Функция вывода элементов структуры
{
    cout<<"\tСамолёт"<<pdt->PlaneName<<" летит на расстояние "<<pdt->FlightDistance<<" км,"<<" перевозит "<<pdt->PlaceNumb<<" пассажиров,"<<endl;
    cout<<"имеет "<<pdt->EngineNumb<<" двигателей,"<<" вылетает в "<<pdt->DepartureTime<<", прибывает в "<<pdt->ArrivalTime<<endl;
    cout<<"и находится в воздухе "<<pdt->FlightHours<<" часов "<<pdt->FlightMinutes<<" минут."<<endl;
}
```

[image: Выполнение]

[image: Ошибка]

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Лучше всего -  использовать `std::string` и `std::vector<>`.

Comment: По-вопросу - как думаете, что вы делаете в этой `cin.getline(spt->PlaneName, sizeof(spt->PlaneName));` строчке?

Comment: Пытаюсь ввести название самолёта.

Comment: Куда вводите и что такое `sizeof(spt->PlaneName)`?

Comment: @GreenDragon, Спасибо за ответ. После исправления строки ввода программа заработала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

В данной строчке происходит попытка записать текст через указатель, который указывает в никуда.

```
    cout<<"Введите название самолёта: ";
    cin.getline(sptr->PlaneName, sizeof(sptr->PlaneName)); <<< !
```

Необходимо предварительно выделять память.

```
    sptr->PlaneName = new char[n];
```

и sizeof(sptr->PlaneName) всегда будет возвращать 4 или 8, так как возвращает размер указателя. А размер зависит от того 32 или 64 разрядная система.

PS: Работаю пол Linux, поэтому не работают conio.h windows.h